# Provisioning Api using Java

Tags: java, api, jpa, provisioning

Hello I tried one application which is used to store First 100 users in my domain to the table using JPA.But its returning Server Error. Pealse Help me.
This is the code i tried..

```
         public class AppsProvisioning {
       public String m[]=new String[1000];
  public int a;
  final EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
//public static void main(String[] args)
 public void calluser() throws AppsForYourDomainException, ServiceException,    
  {

  try {

    // Create a new Apps Provisioning service
    UserService myService = new UserService("My Application");
    myService.setUserCredentials("admin@xxxx.edu.in","xxxxxxxx");

    // Get a list of all entries
    URL metafeedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/a/feeds/domain/user/2.0/");
    System.out.println("Getting user entries...\n");
    UserFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(metafeedUrl, UserFeed.class);
    List<UserEntry> entries = resultFeed.getEntries();
    for(int i=0; i<entries.size(); i++) {

      UserEntry entry = entries.get(i);
      m[i]=entry.getTitle().getPlainText();
      table greeting1 = new table(m[i]);
      em.persist(greeting1);
      System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }


    a=entries.size();
    System.out.println("\nTotal Entries: "+entries.size());
    }


  catch(AuthenticationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(ServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {    
   em.close();
  }
}

}
```

I think error in em.close()
 Error is:Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Regards
Sharun

Comment: Could be helpful to show which line in your code leads to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "domain" in the feed url (https://www.google.com/a/feeds/domain/user/2.0/) with your domain "xxxx.edu.in".

As an alternative, use AppsForYourDomainClient.retrieveAllUsers() as explained in the reference guide http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference_java.html